# Logging into multiple servers simultaneously

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal

We have a service which is a distributed system running across about 16 machines, each doing different things.

When an operational issue is reported, I would ideally like our dev/ops team to be able to log into all 16 servers at once, with an appropriate terminal arrangement on the screen.

How can this be done? We already have SSH keys set up so that the login into each server is pretty quick, but ideally I want to avoid having to log into each server manually, which wastes time when we have a critical issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to have a vm in saved state with all connections / terminals open. When needed you open the vm (should be very quick as it won't need to boot or log in) and all connections and terminals will be there if the servers didn't timeout them.

Answer (score 0):

I really think you need something like [rundeck](http://rundeck.org/). From what you describe you need to run a command against each of the systems to figure out which one is having problems - rundeck would automate that whole process.